# Discord.js How to use black boxes

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I can't use black boxes on Discord that look like this: ``
I can only use them If i use:

```
.setDescription("**Websocket Latency** \n ``test`` \n **API Latency** ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms")
```

So as you can see, it starts and ends with ("") meaning that I can't use `${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms` Anymore As it will literally just send that code of text.

So meaning if i would to do: ``` (`**Websocket Latency** \n ``test`` \n **API Latency** ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`) ```

It will just throw an error.

[click HERE to see the discord message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Chfj.png)

Comment: You mean code blocks, not "black boxes"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using template literals,

```
`${foo}`
```

which are delimited by backticks, you need to escape any backticks with backslashes so they're interpreted as-is:

```
.setDescription(`**Websocket Latency**\n\`test\`\n**API Latency** ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`)
```

To make your example more readable, you could use a multi-line template literal:

```
.setDescription(`**Websocket Latency**
\`test\`
**API Latency** ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`)
```

or join your message from multiple lines:

```
.setDescription(
  [
    "**Websocket Latency**",
    "`test`",
    `**API Latency** ${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp}ms`,
  ].join("\n"),
)
```